# Login with facebook in SharePoint

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, iis, login, claims

**How to login in SharePoint site with facebook login**. i follow the steps from this site. http://ovaismehboob.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/configuring-facebook-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010/ but there are some errors.

it gives **"500 Internal Server Error"** when redirected to our SharePoint Site

Comment: Some errors? Please elaborate :)

Comment: i follow all steps but then after facebook login it gives "keyset does not exist" error

Comment: i think its certificate issue

Answer (score 9):

"Keyset does not exist" means you need to give your web application pool identity account access to your certificate. Do this in the Certificates Snap In.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how do i give access to certificate. there is no way in certificate snap in to give access

Comment: Load the Snap In in MMC as the Computer Account. Under 'Personal', right click the cert then from All Tasks, select Manage Private Keys.

Comment: yes, this problem is solved. but now it gives 500 Internal server error

Comment: Debug with Visual Studio now, as now it smells like a problem in your code behind.

Comment: there is no bug in code..

Comment: facebook user is authenticated in code but when redirected to replytoaddress , it throws error

Comment: Check if the STS is working fine . Try this - Browse to go to IIS Manager --> Sites --> SharePoint WebServices --> SecurityTokenServiceApplication, click on 'Content View' down at the bottom, right click on Securitytoken.svc and click Browse . The expected page of STS should be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I had faced the similar issue when i was working with STS. The reason you get the error is because there is no trust being established between the Sharepoint and STS .
If i am not wrong you might be getting the error at the below lines of code :) This is definitely a certificate issue.

```
                SecurityTokenService sts = new CustomSecurityTokenService(CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.Current);
                SignInResponseMessage responseMessage = FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInRequest(requestMessage, User, sts);
```

Make sure the app pool account which is running the STS code had permissions to access the certificates (STSTestCert) . 
The Identity of the App Pool the Custom STS is running under .Give the Identity read access to the private key of the certifcate used to encypt the SAML token.

The permissions can be added using the certificate MMC snap-in.

2.If doesnt work the STSTestCert might be corrupt or not accessible .Follow http://discusscode.blogspot.com/2012/01/keyset-does-not-exist-issue-in-creating.html,  delete the trust and again try adding the AuthProvider using powershell script.

Comment: yes this problem was solved, but after this, it gives 500 internal server erro

Comment: Check if the STS is working fine . Try this - Browse to go to IIS Manager --> Sites --> SharePoint WebServices --> SecurityTokenServiceApplication, click on 'Content View' down at the bottom, right click on Securitytoken.svc and click Browse . The expected page of STS should be displayed.

Comment: its working , i already checked that

Comment: Is the user present in Sharepoint Group with some permissions ? It might be throwing forbidden error.

Comment: no, its 500 Internal server error